# How to trigger onclick on selection in bixby

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

My app is basically providing three option for selection to the user.

1: I am using `result-view` and `cell-card`. when i was using for each, i was able to click on the card and trigger an intent which is showing user the further details in the form of `compound-card`. Now, for user to select the option by saying first, second OR third, i need to use `navigation-support` and for that I need to use `list-of` in the `result-view`. After using `list-of`, I am unable to trigger the intent `on-click`. How to achieve that?

2: How to trigger that intent, if user is saying first, second or third. Right now, if user is choosing by saying first, second and third, it is popping out the said `cell-card` excluding other two. How to achieve that?

My result-view is:

```
result-view {
  match: ArtistChoiceResult (artistchoice) {
    from-output: ArtistChoice
  }
  message {template("Here is the upcoming event")}
  list-of (artistchoice) {
    navigation-mode {
      read-many {
        page-size(3)
        underflow-statement (This is the first set)
        item-selection-question (Which one would you like?)
        overflow-statement (That's all I have)
      }
    }
    where-each (one) {
      layout-match (one) {
        mode (Summary)
      }
    }
  }
```

`layout-match` is like this

```
 layout {
   match: ArtistChoiceResult (singleArtist)
   mode(Summary)
   content{
    section{
     content{
       cell-card {
        slot1 {
          image {
           url ("#{value(singleArtist.multiple_image)}")
            shape (Square)
          }
        }
        slot2 {
          content {
            order (PrimarySecondary)
            primary ("#{value(singleArtist.multiple_name)}")
            secondary ("#{value(singleArtist.multiple_cat)}")
          }
        }
        on-click {
          intent {
            goal: ArtistChoice
            value-set:MultipleID{$expr(singleArtist.multiple_id)}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

Navigation support file is

```
 navigation-support {
  match: ArtistChoiceResult (this) 
  ordinal-selection-patterns {
    pattern ("(first)[v:viv.core.OrdinalSelector]")
    pattern ("(first)[v:viv.core.OrdinalSelector] one")
    pattern ("that (first)[v:viv.core.OrdinalSelector] one")

    pattern ("yes (first)[v:viv.core.OrdinalSelector]")
    pattern ("yes (first)[v:viv.core.OrdinalSelector] one")
    pattern ("yes that (first)[v:viv.core.OrdinalSelector] one")

    pattern ("result number (one)[v:viv.core.CardinalSelector:1]")
    pattern ("the (first)[v:viv.core.CardinalSelector:1]")

    pattern ("select (first)[v:viv.core.OrdinalSelector] one")
    pattern ("select (first)[v:viv.core.OrdinalSelector]")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues with your code

1. you have created an intent in a Summary layout. The documentation says,
   https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/layout-macro-def.content.cell-card

   > If you have this card to list results with list-of, then clicking the
   >   card opens the selected item in Details mode and the defined intent is not passed
2. If you try to use `layout-match` inside `where-each` the IDE will show a `WARN_DEPRECATED` error. While this might not throw compile errors now, it is advisable to use `layout-macro`

Suggestions to try:

1. Use layout-macro to define your Layouts (both Summary and Details)
2. Add the intent in the Details layout

Comment: I am showing user 3 option then I think summary layout is the better option. Isn't it? I don't want user to click details layout.. is it possible to add intent in summary layout if I am using layout- macro? Also what about issue no 2?

Comment: No, the Bixby framework does not allow it. Refer to the documentation I provided earlier. 

This will become easier to test soon, when the speech functionalities are added to IDE and/or when on-device testing becomes active.

Comment: So right now what to do if user is making selection by speaking first, second or third?

Comment: You can model your capsule behavior from the example on this page https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/enhancing-UX.list-navigation

Comment: By using your suggestion, I used `layout-macro` for summary and details layout. Now, I am saying tell me the scorecard for cricket. if there are three matches for the day , so it will asked user to choose from the following match. IND vs AUS? NZ vs BAN? SA vs PAK. As soon as user will click on the any of the cell-card, this should show the score-card. BUT for now, If user is saying or clicking on first one, It will pop out the first option and remove the other two and then you have to click on the shown option to get the scorecard. So there is one extra-click. I want to avoid that.

Comment: The Shoe sample capsule uses layout-macro and illustrates the functionality of transitioning from Summary view to a Details view, without intermediate views in between. You can use this as a guide to model your own capsule. https://github.com/bixbydevelopers/capsule-sample-shoe