# Extra layout after select card with intent

Tags: bixby

Found this question in other place, similar to [Start playing the audio after selecting card in results view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57233961/start-playing-the-audio-after-selecting-card-in-results-view) and [How to trigger onclick on selection in bixby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54742428/how-to-trigger-onclick-on-selection-in-bixby) but i am unable to comment to ask for further question, and i am so blur about the answer provided, so decided to open a new question.

What i want to achived is to display a list for user to choose and after user choose, it will play the news audio (action 'playnews').

So this is my view which connect to layout macro

```
render{
    list-of (this){
        has-details (true)
        where-each (one){

            layout-macro (display-list){
                param (one){
                    expression (one)
                }
            }
            spoken-summary("#{value(one)}")
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my layout-macro-def

```
layout-macro-def (display-list){
  params{
    param (one){
      type (userWantToHear)
      min (Required) max (One)
    }
  }

  content{
    cell-card{

      slot2{
        content{
          primary{
            template ("#{value(one)}"){
            }
          }
        }
      }
      on-click{
        intent{
          goal: playNews
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What i achieved is when i clicked on the list of selection,

[image]

it bring me to another page with the topic i clicked just now, and the audio play only if i click the card on the new page shown.

[image]

Yes this question is similar to those i mentioned above, but i require a further explanation as i really blur about this (and yea i can't post a comment).I want to get rid of the one-extra-click before the audio play.

Thanks  !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the easy answer: 
Unfortunately, `on-click` does not work on `list-of` in result-view. So the extra page is required when doing the `on-click` way of the result-view.

Now the useful answer: 
To implement the feature you want, an input-view with `selection-of` might be much easier than `list-of` in result-view. 
This might be difficult to explain in words, so I made a sample capsule, you can [download it](https://github.com/MinChengVivLabs/playground.nodetailview) and try.

In the two training examples provided, **show me all titles** use the result-view, and redirect using on-click. While **play title** directly use the action which triggers an input-view.

As it shows here, no extra page, one click, the same result. 
[image]